# Facebook c# sdk client login + xulrunner cookies

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies, authentication, xulrunner

I am trying to make an application with Facebook C# SDK,,I am usin xulrunner+Gecko Fx for browser,,I can login but I need to login with multiple accounts..I am removing all cookies after login and I can login with other account too and keep access tokens and I can send or get posts..But when i try to see any page on facebook with my program I cant see because i removed cookies and it need login again..I tired everything but couldnt find any solution,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't just remove the cookies but save them and restore the right set of cookies when it is needed. Something along the lines:

```
function removeAndReturnCookies(host)
{
  var removedCookies = [];
  var cookieManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"]
                                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager2);
  var e = cookieManager.getCookiesFromHost(host);
  while (e.hasMoreElements())
  {
    var cookie = e.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsICookie2);
    cookieManager.remove(cookie.host, cookie.name, cookie.path, false);
    removedCookies.push(cookie);
  }
}

function restoreCookies(cookies)
{
  var cookieManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"]
                                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager2);
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
  {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    cookieManager.add(cookie.host, cookie.path, cookie.name, cookie.value,
                      cookie.isSecure, cookie.isHttpOnly, cookie.isSession,
                      cookie.expiry);
  }
}

var cookies = removeAndReturnCookies("facebook.com");
restoreCookies(cookies);
```

I didn't test this code but something like that should work. Documentation links:

- [nsICookieManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager)
- [nsICookieManager2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager2) (inherits from `nsICookieManager`)
- [nsICookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookie)
- [nsICookie2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookie2) (inherits from `nsICookie`)

Comment: I was tried this but it wasnt work but your code worked :) thank you :)